# cannot add xml file to zip laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-ziparchive

I want to create a zip folder that includes an xml file and download it. I can download zip but it is empty.

I can create xml and zip :

[image]

By the way, $result is the result of ArrayToXml::convert(array,....)

```php
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
   
        $fileName = 'example-'.time().'.xml';
        $zipName = 'example'.time().'.zip';

        if ($zip->open(public_path("storage/zips/".$zipName), ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)
        {
            Storage::disk('public')->put('/files/'.$fileName, $result);        
            $zip->addFile(public_path("storage/files/".$fileName), $result);
            Storage::disk('public')->put('/zips/'.$zipName, $zip);       
          
            $zip->close();           
        }
        return response()->download(storage_path('app\public\zips\\'.$zipName));
```

How to add xml file to zip. I am new to laravel please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Madzipper](https://github.com/madnest/madzipper) package. Makes working with zip files very easy.

You can create a zipfile as follows:

```php
$fileName = 'example-'.time() . '.xml';
$zip = 'public/zips/example' . time() . '.zip';

Madzipper::make($zip)->addString($fileName, $result)->close();
```

And then return the path to `$zip` when downloading the file.

Please have a look at [the docs](https://github.com/madnest/madzipper#functions) for more info.

Comment: You're welcome @ertyu. Please consider accepting or upvoting this answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers